# Does any one know how to disable the script when the menu changes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want the ball to stop spawning when the restart menu is enabled but I can't get it to work at all can some please help.
Here is the script

```
void Start()
{
    
    StartCoroutine(SpawnBallLoop());
    
}

IEnumerator SpawnBallLoop()
{
    while (gameOver == false)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2f);
        SpawnBall();
       
    }
}

void SpawnBall()
{
    Instantiate(ball, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.18f, 2.18f), 4.6f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Does this refer to Unity? Then please tag your question acordingly

Comment: I don't see any code for a menu in your snippet ... In general: either set `gameOver = true` .. use `StopCoroutine` ... disable this script ... destroy it ... there are so many possible solutions depending on your usecase .....

Answer (score 0):

You can use StopCoroutine like Hugo said, but then I fail to see the point in even checking for `gameOver` in the while condition. Truly I think it is redundant in any case:

If you would set `gameOver` to `true`, you would effectively stop the while loop, so balls *should* stop spawning. But then you would still have to restart the Coroutine as `gameOver` turns false again, hence fully eliminating the need for the `while` condition.